# How to speed up the build and run process in unity for mobile devices iOS/Android

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Hi I'm developing a game in unity and I need test this game in iOS.  For particular case I need test the input touch for controllers but this takes much time.

When I change some lines of code in script C#, I must re-build iOS game in unity, after that I must build and run the Xcode project for testing and run the game on my iPhone.

This process takes much time, so the question is if there are 
some ways to accelerate this process ?

Comment: There's also a [related post on the game dev stack exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/103994/115296). Unity Remote still seems to be as good as it gets for this purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Unity Remote 5** is designed to do. It reduces the amount of time you deploy your app to your iOS or Android device during development. You can get the iOS version [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/unity-remote-5/id871767552?mt=8) and the Android version [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.unity3d.genericremote&hl=en).

It supports the following sensors:

- Touch
- Accelerometer
- Gyroscope
- Webcam
- Screen orientation change events

The latest version which is `5.0` added support for the following:

**Android**:

- Gamepads connected to the remote device
- Compass and location data(GPS)

**iOS**:

- MFi gamepads connected to the remote device (requires Unity 5.4)
- 3D Touch and Apple Pencil support
- Apple TV devices
- Compass and location data(GPS)

When you download the app linked above, connect your iOS device to your computer, open the app.

From Unity Editor, go to 
**Edit**->**Project Settings**->**Editor** then chose your device(iOS) from the device drop down menu. Click play and you will be able to test your touch functions from the Editor.

Even with this App, it is recommended to test your app on the actual device once in  while. So at-least, do this once in a day to make sure everything is working as it should.