# Use Device Camera instead of Webcam on Play

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I've downloaded and used Vuforia with success and when I play the project, It uses my webcam on my laptop. But how can I use my connected iPhone's camera instead when I play the project in Unity?

Comment: Deploy it to the device, perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: **You can't**.

Vuforia accesses the camera hardware directly with C++ and not with Unity's  [`WebCamTexture`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.html) API. This would have worked with the new [Unity Remote 5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39107871/3785314) if they used `WebCamTexture` in their API to get camera frames, but they didn't because `WebCamTexture` is extremely slow for image processing.