# Unity remote 4 and 5 Not working on Oppo Mirror 5, Samsung Galaxy S7Edge?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have installed unity remote 4 and 5. When I run my editor Both of it not working with my device. The device doesn't show anything.

Iam using Unity 5.35f1. I have do :

1. Edit-> project Setting-> Device (Any Device Andorid)
2. I have end task Adb in start manager.

But still not working.

What should I do ?

Thanks

Dennis

Comment: You need to first install adb interface driver for your android device.

Comment: @UmeshVerma I think this is the problem. I have use a not original cable USB. It can't detect automatically on my computer. So i change the original. and it detect automatically. Now my unity remote 4 can run. But seem the graphic color is so bad not like originat. What is the problem ?  and so for unity remote 5 it is still not effect anything.

Comment: I don't think you understand what Unity Remote is used for. It is not meant for graphics. You have to build the Game to see the actual graphics. Unity Remote is meant to make it easier to use sensors such as Acceleromer, touch and GPS on the Editor. That's it. The graphic you see is just for a guide. To read more about this, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107153/how-to-speed-up-the-build-and-run-process-in-unity-for-mobile-devices-ios-androi).

Comment: Yeah i got it. So that's not about the graphic. The graphic will not effect anything. THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes as it say in comment, the solution for me is make sure your usb driver android phone is detect by the computer. Then make sure again run unity remote first before run Unity.