# Unity Moving Player along X-axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

I am trying to create a player movement along the x-axis based on finger position.

**What I need to Happen:** Not multi-Touch. I want it so a player can put a single finger down and grab that position. Then check to see if the player dragged finger along screen on x-axis and move player left or right based off where they dragged finger from first touch.

So if they touch the screen and if drag left: move left by speed and if it changes to drag right move right by speed.

Any help would be Awesome.

Comment: please show us your research effort, what have you already tried and post your current relevant code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way would be to stored first touch position and then compare the X with that position:

```
public class PlayerMover : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// Movement speed units per second
    [SerializeField]
    private float speed;

    /// X coordinate of the initial press
    // The '?' makes the float nullable
    private float? pressX;



    /// Called once every frame
    private void Update()
    {
        // If pressed with one finger
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            pressX = Input.touches[0].position.x;
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            pressX = null;


        if(pressX != null)
        {
            float currentX = Input.touches[0].position.x;

            // The finger of initial press is now left of the press position
            if(currentX < pressX)
                Move(-speed);

            // The finger of initial press is now right of the press position
            else if(currentX > pressX)
                Move(speed);

            // else is not required as if you manage (somehow)
            // move you finger back to initial X coordinate
            // you should just be staying still
        }
    }


    `
    /// Moves the player
    private void Move(float velocity)
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.right * velocity * Time.deltaTime;
    }

}
```

**WARNING:** this solution will only work for devices with touch input available (because of Input.touches use).

Comment: Could you tell me what the ? after float is called or a link to understand that better? Everything works fine on device For anyone else looking, you just cant run it in editor.

Comment: I wrote a warning at the bottom of the answer, saying that this works only in devices with touch input. As for reference on '?', see  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/index#nullable-types-overview („The syntax T? is shorthand for Nullable<T>, where T is a value type. The two forms are interchangeable.“)

Answer (score 2):

using the code @programmer provided in this answer: [Detect swipe gesture direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41491765/detect-swipe-gesture-direction)

You can easily detect the direction you are swiping/dragging. Replace the Debug

```
 void OnSwipeLeft()
{
    Debug.Log("Swipe Left");
}

void OnSwipeRight()
{
    Debug.Log("Swipe Right");
}
```

With functions that move your character. If you use RigidBody to move your character you can use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html. If its a normal object, you can move it by tweaking the `transform.position`.

If you need more information on how to move rigidbody\normal objects let me know what type of game you have and more details on how you set up the player.