# Swipe movement to a defined coordinate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making an endless runner on Unity. There was a problem, how to make that when swiping up, the cube moved by 0.5 on the Z axis, and similarly, when swiping down, by -0.5 on the z axis.

P.S. that is, the cube has a position of 0, when swiping up, it moves to the coordinate 0.5, when swiping up again, it moves to the coordinate 1, etc.

I also attached a photo with my idea.

[Cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kZdo.png)

Comment: does this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41491765/detect-swipe-gesture-direction) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect swipe gesture direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41491765/detect-swipe-gesture-direction)