# Destroy GetMouseButtonDown event and position or force mousebuttonup

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouse-position

When I run my app on Android, the first finger touch calls `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)`
and the second touch calls `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)`.
I want to override `GetMouseButtonDown(0)` in some cases- so the second finger (1) touch will become the first (0) and I don't know how to do it.
Either this or how to force `mouseButtonUp` on the first finger touch- I want to remove this first "click" from the system so it'll not use `Input.mousePosition` in a case of 2 touches.

Why?
I'm creating a paint app when the user can draw lines.
There is an area when the user can paint (in a rectangle) and an area where he shouldn't, I know how to detect when pressed on unwanted area.
But sometimes the palm of my hand creates unwanted first touch `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` on the unwanted area (without `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)`) and when I start to draw a line 
`Input.mousePosition` gets the average of both touches,  so I just want a way to remove a "down" touch/click from the system. Or another way to solve my problem.

Here is my code:

```
 if (Input.touchCount == 0)
    { screenPoint = new Vector3(0, 0, 0); 
     currentTouch = 4;  //currentTouch is for GetMouseButtonUp(currentTouch)  }

    for (int i=0; i< Input.touchCount; i++)
    {
      touch = Input.GetTouch(i);
      screenPointTemp = touch.position;
      screenPointTemp3 = new Vector3(screenPointTemp.x, screenPointTemp.y, zCam);

       //if the touch is in a "good" zone-
      if (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPointTemp3).z > BottomNod.transform.position.z - nodeScale) 
      {
          screenPoint = touch.position;
          currentTouch = i;
       }

        }
    }

if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(currentTouch))
        {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working on mobile devices to detect a touch on the screen without clicking on any object, you should be using `Input.touchCount` with `Input.GetTouch` or `Input.touches`. Although I highly recommend `Input.GetTouch` since that doesn't even allocate temporary variables like `Input.touches`. To get the postion of the touch use, `Input.GetTouch(index).position`.

Each of these functions returns [`Touch`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch.html) so you can use [`Touch.fingerId`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-fingerId.html) to detect/keep track of how many touches you want at the-same time. You can also use the index that is passed in to `Input.GetTouch` to keep track of the touch. That's totally up to you.

This detects **every** touch down, move and up on mobile devices:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i)
{
    //Touch Down
    if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {

    }

    //Touch Moved
    if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {

    }

    //Touch Up
    if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {

    }
}
```

Limit to one touch only(Use index 0):

```
if (Input.touchCount == 1)
{
    //Touch Down
    if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {

    }

    //Touch Moved
    if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        //Draw?
    }

    //Touch Up
    if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {

    }
}
```

Like I said, you can limit this with `fingerId`. The implementation depends on what exactly that you want.

Comment: Hey thanks, I shouldn't limit to one touch because if I do- when the user touches the first touch (by a mistake) with his palm on an unwanted zone without noticing, he won't understand why when he touches the screen (second touch) nothing will happen...   I added my code to my question, this was my solution but I still have problems-   when the first touch is wrong and second is right, when I release the first touch (GetMouseButtonUp(CurrentTouch))== true,  and I don't want it to be true.

Comment: Also when I use- Input.GetTouch I can't test it on unity with my mouse

Comment: You need to use [Unity Remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107153/how-to-speed-up-the-build-and-run-process-in-unity-for-mobile-devices-ios-androi/39107871#39107871) to test it or use Unity macro (`#if UNITY_EDITOR`) to separate  the `GetMouseButtonUp` code.

Comment: *"when the user touches the first touch (by a mistake) with his palm on an unwanted zone without noticing, he won't understand why when he touches the screen (second touch) nothing will happen"* In that case, the first touch should be considered as valid and be used but while the first touch is still on, the rest of the touches should be ignored?

Comment: In this specific case, the first touch which is a mistake should be ignored-  and the second one should be the valid one. Your answer wasn't exactly the solution but I replaced my GetMouseButtonUp with your TouchPhase.Ended and it solved my problem so thanks.

Comment: Yeah. It wasn't made to me direct answer. It was made to show you which API you should be using. Glad I was able to help.