# Unity3D: Timer created at TouchEnded not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

Using Unity3d 2018.2.1 and C#

Problem: StartTimer not starting when user clicks screen, touch not being registered so timer never starts.

In FixedUpdate() im looking at when the user touches the screen to start a timer.
If the user hasn't touched the screen again and it has been 15 seconds then do something. If the user touches the screen before the 15 seconds, then restart the timer.

```
public float uiStartTime = 0f;
public float uiCurrentTime = 0f;
public float uiMaxTime = 15f;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            uiStartTime = Time.time;
        }
    }

    uiCurrentTime = Time.time;

    if (uiStartTime - uiCurrentTime == uiMaxTime)
    {
        //  Reset Timer
        uiStartTime = 0f;
        uiCurrentTime = 0f;

        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: Put `Debud.Log` inside `if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)` and see if that would be called

Comment: it does not get called

Comment: @Programmer also, im using a mouse to test but will deploy for mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem: StartTimer not starting when user clicks screen, touch not
>   being registered so timer never starts.Im using a mouse to test but
>   will deploy for mobile

That's the main issue here. Of-course you still have some logical error in your code but timer shouldn't start since you're using mouse to test the `Input.touchCount` and `Input.GetTouch` API. These two API only work on the mobile device since they use touch instead of mouse.

If you want to use them in the Editor, use **Unity Remote 5**. Download it, on your mobile device, enable it in the Editor by going to **Edit**->**Project Settings**->**Editor** then connect your device to your computer. You should be able to use the touch API in your Editor without having to build it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107153/how-to-speed-up-the-build-and-run-process-in-unity-for-mobile-devices-ios-androi/39107871#39107871) post for more information about *Unity Remote 5*.

---

If you want the code to be more compatible with both mouse and touch then make a simple function that wraps around the touch and mouse API. You can then use the combination of `UNITY_STANDALONE` and `UNITY_EDITOR` preprocessor directives to detect when you are not running on a mobile platform.

Here is a simple mobile/desktop touch wrapper that works without *Unity Remote 5*:

```
bool ScreenTouched(out TouchPhase touchPhase)
{
    #if UNITY_STANDALONE || UNITY_EDITOR
    //DESKTOP COMPUTERS
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        touchPhase = TouchPhase.Began;
        return true;
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        touchPhase = TouchPhase.Ended;
        return true;
    }
    touchPhase = TouchPhase.Canceled;
    return false;
    #else

    //MOBILE DEVICES
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        touchPhase = Input.GetTouch(0).phase;
        return true;
    }
    touchPhase = TouchPhase.Canceled;
    return false;
    #endif
}
```

Below is how to use it to get what you want in your question:

```
public float uiStartTime = 0;
public float uiMaxTime = 15f;
private bool timerRunning = false;

private void Update()
{
    //Increment timer if it's running
    if (timerRunning)
        uiStartTime += Time.deltaTime;

    TouchPhase touchPhase;

    if (ScreenTouched(out touchPhase))
    {
        //Check for keypres and start timer if it's not running
        if (touchPhase == TouchPhase.Ended && !timerRunning)
        {
            timerRunning = true;
        }

        //If the user touches the screen before the 15 seconds, then restart the timer.
        else if (touchPhase == TouchPhase.Ended && timerRunning && uiStartTime < uiMaxTime)
        {
            uiStartTime = 0f;
            Debug.Log("Timer Reset");
        }
    }

    //If the user hasn't touched the screen again and it has been 15 seconds then do something.
    if (uiStartTime >= uiMaxTime)
    {
        // Do Something
        Debug.Log("Timer not touched for 15 seconds");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your equality will essentially never be true when using floats. `uiStartime - uiCurrentTime` is also giving you a negative number.
Instead do:

```
   if (uiCurrentTime - uiStartTime >= uiMaxTime)
```