# Make Build and Run faster

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to build an apk faster? (by disabling some shader compilation, for example Hidden/Post FX/Uber Shader takes most of the build time)

p.s. Yes I know about Unity Remote and use it - this time I need exactly Build and Run

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to speed up the build and run process in unity for mobile devices iOS/Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107153/how-to-speed-up-the-build-and-run-process-in-unity-for-mobile-devices-ios-androi)

Comment: Wait [until 2019.1](https://unity3d.com/unity/alpha/2019.1.0a9) when patch build is available. `Android: Added Package Patching functionality, where only script related changes are sent to device instead of repackaging apk file.`

Comment: Thanks Draco18s, but if I change the objects' positions will it update them?